# What is the purpose of sized array as function argument is c and c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arguments

Consider the following functions:

```
void func1(int unsized_array[]){}
void func2(int sized_array[10]){}
void func3(int *pointer){}
```

According to the result of:

```
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(func1), decltype(func2)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(func2), decltype(func3)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(func3), decltype(func1)>::value << std::endl;
```

Types of these 3 functions is the same. Also inside the function`func2`,   `sizeof`operator does not provide the size of array elements all combined.

So what is the purpose of sized array as function argument (like `func2`)?

Comment: This is not `c`, so why the tag?

Comment: @Devolus but that comes from C. The C++ here is just a way to detect what the compiler considers.

Comment: @Devolus I agree that std::is_same is not c but originally I saw this type of usage (sized array as function argument) in c code

Comment: All three variants are the same in C and in C++. There is no real purpose of declaring the array size like in `func2`. The size might be used for documentation purposes.

Comment: Yes, arrays as function parameters automatically decay to pointers so the 3 proposals are identical (and this is also the reason why the size is not "seen" inside the function's body, `sizeof` will return the size of the pointer, not the size of the array)

Comment: I would use `void func4(int (&sized_array)[10]){}` if size is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Since array declarators generally may have size expressions (as when defining an array other than in a parameter or when declaring a parameter that contains an array as a sub-part, such as a pointer to an array), it would take more work to exclude it from the grammar than to leave it in harmlessly. (There are numerous constructions in C that can result in no effect, such as a statement expression with no side effects (`3*4;`), the left operand of a comma expression with no side effects, a function or loop with an empty body, and so on. It would take a lot of work to exclude things that have no effect from the language.)
2. Array sizes in parameters do alter the meaning when the `static` keyword is present; `void func2(int asd[static 10])` declares a function that must be passed a pointer to the first of at least ten elements, which is different from the meaning of the other declarations. (And this would compound the problem of excluding a size expression from the grammar of an array parameter declaration, as it would be necessary to ban a bare size but not one with `static`.)
3. The array size may be useful documentation to the function implementor and to the function user.
4. The array size is evaluated. If, for example, the definition is `void func2(int asd[printf("Hello")]) {}`, then “Hello” will be printed when the function is called. (Some compilers might not do this; the C standard is unclear on it.)
5. A compiler could use the size expression to emit warnings if it sees the function uses more than the stated number of elements or a caller passes fewer than the stated number. (Clang 11 appears not to do the former and not to do the latter unless `static` is used.)

Comment: I don't really agree with `3` as this is not garuantueed, and thus will most likely be wrong to rely on such documentation.

Comment: @Devolus: Comments are also not guaranteed but may be useful documentation. Arguing that they may be wrong is not a rebuttal to the fact that they may be useful.

Comment: I know. That's why I usually try not to comment the code, but document the algorithm. :)

Comment: @Devolus: Documentation of the algorithm is also not guaranteed.

Comment: @Devolus #3 is the best reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. I have to say that reasons 2 and 4 were very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There is no purpose as they all decay to the same type, as you correctly identified. For C++ this behavior is inherited from C.

Just like how adding `const` to a non-reference argument and other keywords won't change anything to the outside, they will all result to the `void(int)` signature.

```
void foo1(int a) {}
void foo2(const int a) {}
void foo3(volatile int a) {}
```

---

But instead of `int[10]` you can have something that actually works:

```
void func2(int(&asd)[10]) {}
```

This will only accept `int` arrays with size 10. You will now also be able use `sizeof` to get the array size at compile time, which was not possible for `int[10]` obviously.

Comment: thank you for reminding me of ```void func2(int(&asd)[10]) {}```. I completely forgot about that